# Is it safe to ignore these proguard notes for kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I don't understand why I'm getting these notes from proguard and if I've to do anything to address them.

```
Note: kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt: can't find dynamically referenced class 
kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations 
Note: kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt: can't find dynamically referenced class 
kotlin.internal.JRE8PlatformImplementations 
Note: kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt: can't find dynamically referenced class 
kotlin.internal.JRE7PlatformImplementations 

Note: kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection: can't find dynamically referenced class 
kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl
```

Three of them are for `kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationKt` and one for `kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection`

### My setup

```
kotlin: 1.2.71
Android Studio / gradle plugin: 3.2.0
gradle: 4.10.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is safe, you should add those rules to your `proguard-rules.pro` configuration

```
# Kotlin
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-dontnote kotlin.internal.PlatformImplementationsKt
-dontnote kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.**
```

Comment: OK. I've general understanding of why proguard provides `can't find dynamically referenced class` note. Any idea why we get these specific notes for kotlin?

Comment: This probably depends on how Kotlin works, probably it is trying to check which version of the JVM it's running to using the available implementation (I'm speculating base on the message you posted). This warning should be part of the internal implementation of proguard of Android Studio so there could be a day where you won't need them anymore (this happened a lot of times in the past).