# Kotlin Reflection with Proguard - Incomplete hierarchy for class

Tags: java, android, reflection, kotlin, proguard

I'm running into an issue at runtime when using Proguard with Kotlin reflection. Basically, when I am calling [`KClass.declaredMemberProperties`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/declared-member-properties.html), I get:

```
Incomplete hierarchy for class FieldBoundObject, unresolved classes [com.example.test.classes.DisposableObject]
kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.components.RuntimeErrorReporter.reportIncompleteHierarchy
```

Here is the relevant stacktrace:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incomplete hierarchy for class FieldBoundObject, unresolved classes [com.example.test.classes.DisposableObject]
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.components.RuntimeErrorReporter.reportIncompleteHierarchy(RuntimeErrorReporter.kt:26)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassTypeConstructor.computeSupertypes(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:181)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.AbstractTypeConstructor$supertypes$1.invoke(AbstractTypeConstructor.kt:34)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.AbstractTypeConstructor$supertypes$1.invoke(AbstractTypeConstructor.kt:22)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:354)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:410)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.AbstractTypeConstructor.getSupertypes(AbstractTypeConstructor.kt:23)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getNonDeclaredFunctionNames(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:278)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$functionNamesLazy$2.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:73)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$functionNamesLazy$2.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:40)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:354)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:410)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.StorageKt.getValue(storage.kt:42)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.getFunctionNamesLazy(DeserializedMemberScope.kt)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.getFunctionNames(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:84)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope.computeFunctionNames(LazyJavaClassMemberScope.kt:75)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope.computeFunctionNames(LazyJavaClassMemberScope.kt:65)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope.computeNonDeclaredFunctions(LazyJavaScope.kt:342)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(LazyJavaScope.kt:61)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(LazyJavaScope.kt:55)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:354)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:410)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope.getContributedDescriptors(LazyJavaScope.kt:323)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedDescriptors$default(ResolutionScope.kt:52)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KDeclarationContainerImpl.getProperties(KDeclarationContainerImpl.kt:64)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:151)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$declaredNonStaticMembers$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:44)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:92)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:31)
   at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getDeclaredNonStaticMembers(KClassImpl.kt)
   at kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.getDeclaredMemberProperties(KClasses.kt:163)
   at com.example.test.classes.FieldBinder.bindFields(FieldBinder.kt:51)
   at com.example.test.classes.FieldBinder.(FieldBinder.kt:28)
   at com.example.test.classes.FieldBoundObject.(FieldBoundObject.kt:15)
   at com.example.test.models.TestClass.(TestClass.java:52)
   at com.example.test.models.TestClass.(TestClass.java:58)
   at com.example.test.ReactLandingActivity.startClass(ReactLandingActivity.java:93)
```

Here is the relevant call in `Fieldbinder.kt`:

```
class FieldBinder(receiver: Any) {

    private fun bindFields(receiver: Any, classToCheck: Class<*>) {
        for (property in classToCheck.kotlin.declaredMemberProperties) {
            //...
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here is the signature for the "missing" class `DisposableObject`

```
package com.example.test.classes

open class DisposableObject : ScopeProvider, Dispose {

    //...
}
```

I think it has something to do with name obfuscation. I've tried using `@Keep` on the actual class itself, as well as using `-keep class` on the class itself in my Proguard file. However, what DOES solve the problem is keeping names in Proguard:

```
-dontobfuscate
```

or

```
-keepnames class com.example.test.classes.DisposableObject
```

Is there an issue with name obfuscation and Kotlin reflection? I'm not having the same issues with Java reflection. Or is there a better way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding:
`-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.** { *; }` to proguard file?

Comment: I currently have `-keep public class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.** { public *; }` - I'm not sure exactly where I got that, but I'll try yours.

Comment: That worked! I'm not sure where I got the other Proguard config. Thanks!

Comment: I think here you can find other Kotlin proguard configs if you need them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52689769/2910520

Comment: @MatPag I was mistaken - this still remains an issue even with your recommended proguard settings. I am using `dontobfuscate` for now, but I'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Have you tried `-keep class com.example.test.classes.DisposableObject { *; }` rather than just trying to keep the name?

Comment: Yup, I've tried `-keep class com.example.test.classes.** { *; }` as well as that line. Neither helps. I think the class is clearly there if both `keepnames` and `dontobfuscate` solve the problem.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Comment: If you use dontobfuscate, obfuscation does not appear. Were there any other solutions?

Comment: I faced same error but i can't fixed. I wrote reflection method with Java for this reason.

Comment: Same issue here, can't find a solution. I've tried several different configs on my proguard file but it doesn't work. I think it's a bug on Kotlin 1.4, they've changed some stuff on Reflect.